# Persist window screen for dynamic ID

Tags: xul, xulrunner

I wanted to persist window position. But the case is windows id are dynamic.

Here is the detail scenario..
dynamic_id will be one of `"id1", "id2" ... "id5"`// these are fixed
`window.openDialog("chrome://something/content/test.xul, name, dynamic_id)`

and my `test.xul` is

`<window persist="screenX screenY" .....  >/<window>`

Now how could I achieve persistance of window.

I tried adding 
`window.id = dynamic_id`, But it doesn't works..

Or If there is a way to do something like below:
`<window id = "dynamic_id" persist= ..../></window>`

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

that is becuease the url is always the same, and this is the "id" that mozilla use to remember "the persisting things" in its database of "persisting things".

Do this:

```
openDialog("chrome://something/content/test.xul?id=" + dinamic_id, name )
```

then in your text.xul, you have to obtain the id, do this:

```
id = location.search.match( /id=([^&]+)/ ) && RegExp.$1
```